# How the removal of ING from lingering affects the given verse

Tags: word-usage

I have an English tutor who gave me some homework the other day. And I found a poetry of some sort in the homework I was supposed to do. (it's his notebook)

> "In my burnished throne I sit,
>   thinking of all that could've been,
>   perceptions of death **lingering** in my head as I wait to die."
>
> "In my burnished throne I sit,
>   thinking of all that could've been,
>   perceptions of death **linger** in my head as I wait to die."

Does removing the *-ing* from *lingering* make any significant difference in the verse? Does it make any difference meaning-wise?

Comment: There isn't much difference in meaning between the two phrases, but but the second one is a run-on (ungrammatical).  It should read:  _"In my burnished throne I sit, thinking of all that could've been.  **P**erceptions of death linger in my head as I wait to die."_

Comment: Another possible fix (if you cross that *ing* out): cross the last comma out and use a semicolon instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a big grammatical difference. With "lingering", the line "perceptions of death lingering in my head as I wait to die" is a non-finite clause functioning as a sentence modifier. Functionally it is no different from an adjectival clause phrase like "my mood sombre".

With "linger", the line "perceptions of death linger in my head as I wait to die" is a complete sentence. In prose, this would be a run-on sentence, as it is a second sentence joined to the first with no conjunction clarifying the relationship of the two parts. Poetry is often less rigid about such rules, so you may find such a pattern in poetry.

I can find little difference of meaning between them; but the different structure has an effect: I find the second clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences give the image of a perception that stuck around in your head.
However, a difference may be a nuance in activeness, consider

> I took a walk in the woods
>   I went walking in the woods

The second sentence may give a more "active" image or impression than the first sentence.

Also, in your passage, the linger-"ing" more closely mirrors think-"ing"